# HTMLUnit does not process jsonp request

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, gwt, jsonp, htmlunit

I am trying to crawl my GWT app with HTMLUnit, but for a certain page the desired content is not returned. The GWT page contains a dynamically added javascript which makes a jsonp request to a gae server. I already debugged the server code, and the breakpoint is hit, but at this time the htmlunit code is already finished and the returned content is not complete.

I almost tried all suggested solutions available in stackoverflow, but without any success.

Here is the jsonp request.

```
http://30.tripstorekrabi.appspot.com/activity?&callback=__gwt_jsonp__.P0.onSuccess
```

On other pages I use exactly the same kind of call, and there it works fine.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround in my GWT code:

Now the jsonp request is executed in a deferred scheduled command:

```
 Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
  @Override
  public void execute() {
    activityRegistry.loadActivities(new AsyncCallback<Result>() {
  }
```

Now the javascript function is processed from htmlunit and the desired content is showed.